# How to get previous and middle dates in each group using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
'time_1' :['2173/04/01 12:35:00','2173/04/01 12:50:00','2173/04/02 12:59:00','2173/04/02 13:14:00','2173/04/04 13:37:00','2173/04/06 13:39:00','2173/04/06 11:30:00','2173/04/08 16:00:00','2173/04/09 22:00:00','2173/04/11 04:00:00','2173/04/13 04:30:00','2173/04/14 08:00:00'],
 'val' :[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
})
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
```

[image]

What I would like to do is, `for each subject, get two days`, based on a condition given below

`val = 1`- **Fetch previous two days (from val = 1)**

`val = 0`- **Fetch middle two days of his duration**

This is what I tried, but it isn't elegant or accurate.

```
con = lambda x: (x.eq(1))
con_1 = lambda x: (x.eq(0))
df.loc[df.groupby('subject_id')['val'].transform(con)]['time_1'] - timedelta(days = 2)
```

Following is my expected output:

[image]

`subject = 1` has `val = 1`, so we get `previous two days from val = 1` for him and for `subject = 2`, as there is no `val = 1`, we get `middle 2 days of his duration` (8th - 14th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
def func(x):
    floor = x['time_1'].dt.floor('d')

    if (x['val'].any()):
        date = x.loc[x['val'] == 1, 'time_1'].iat[0].floor('d')
        new_date = date - pd.Timedelta(3, unit='d')
        return (x[floor.between(new_date, date, inclusive=False)])
    else:
        date = floor.mean().floor('d')
        new_date = date + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
        return (x[floor.between(date, new_date)])

df = df.groupby('subject_id', group_keys=False).apply(func)
print (df)
   subject_id              time_1  val  day
2           1 2173-04-02 12:59:00    0    2
3           1 2173-04-02 13:14:00    0    2
9           2 2173-04-11 04:00:00    0   11
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But I need to get previous two days and not previous two rows. In this case, `val was 1 on 2173-04-04 13:37:00`,so we get `04-03` and `04-02`. In this example we don't have `04-03`, so it's just all records from `04-02`. Upvoted

Comment: @SSMK - So logic is if value is `1` get datetimes, here `2173-04-04`, subtract 2 days to `2173-04-02` and return first datetimes with `2173-04-02` per group?

Comment: If `val is 1` on `2173-04-04`, then subtract 2 days which results in `2173-04-02`. then get all the records from `2173-04-02` to `2173-04-03`. As we don't have `2173-04-03` in this example, we don't see them. If 1 record for 3rd was there, we expect to see 3 records as output. 2 record for `2173-04-02` and 1 for `2173-04-03`.

Comment: If `val is 0`, then get the middle dates of this duration. Let's say we had records from 10th Jan to 18th Jan with all `val = 0`. then we expect to get (`18-10`)/`2` = `4`. So 4th day in this duration (10-18th) is `14th` and next one `15th`.

Comment: Will try your new one. Thank you

Comment: Should the index for middle scenario be `x.index[i:i+1]`? Why is it `i-1:i+1`?

Comment: @SSMK - I just see your comment for `0`, it is wrong.

Comment: Okay, will wait. Thank you

Comment: @SSMK - if test mean of second group get `2173-04-11 00:00:00` (testing values with no times), next is `2173-04-12 00:00:00` so output is only one row, because only one row for `2173-04-11 00:00:00` and no row for `2173-04-12 00:00:00`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199223/discussion-between-ssmk-and-jezrael).